# How to use Cloud Storage to multipart upload Music/Video (for Laravel)?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I'm thinking using S3 Amazon for storage (if you guys have better one, don't hesitate to recommend). I could do a normal file upload, but let's say I'm uploading a very large video/music file (something > 20mb), I will hit php upload maxfilesize.

Yes I can just set `php_max_filesize` value but I am thinking something else.

How to break those files into smaller chunks, and upload each chunks (like how you download torrent files, they each have the download chunks)? And stopping and continuing them anytime the user wants?

This (http://www.hjsplit.org/php/) does not work, because it needs to read the file **ON THE SERVER** first, before uploading it, so it's useless. Are there any Laravel/PHP/JS library for this?

Or, I wonder how youtube did it?

Answer (score 0):

The way Chunked Uploads work is by splitting the files into pieces in Javascript and sending the pieces numbered to the backend, and then the backend typically just copies the content of each chunk it receives into a file it creates and keeps counting up the size of the chunks until they make up the full size of the original file you wanted to upload.

As far as packages, look at the official AWS SDK for PHP http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuPHP.html

Look at the second example which uses their multipart upload feature.